# Azure Function App Consumption , with Azure Blob Storage V1 or V2

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

From experience does it make a difference if Azure Function App Consumption plan uses Blob Storage V1 or V2.

It seem that the Storage transaction on V1 is 1/10 of what is on V2?

Or am I miss understanding something?

Comment: would depend on what the storage is used for and how much.

Comment: I am using it to host my Function APP

Answer (score 1):

> From experience does it make a difference if Azure Function App
> COnsumption plane uses Blob Storage V1 or V2.

It would depend on the features you're using. If you're using storage as a simple object store, then it would not make any difference whether you use V1 or V2. You would want to use V2 if you have a need for features that are available in V2 only. Some of these features are:

- Support for blob access tiers (Hot, Cool, Archive).
- Support for blob versioning.
- Support for blob tags etc.

V2 is definitely way more expensive than V1 so going for V2 makes sense only if you're using the features available in V2 only.

I read somewhere that Azure Storage Team is making the price of V1 and V2 same (not sure if they are increasing V1 pricing or decreasing V2 pricing) however looking at the pricing page, I can still see that V2 is about 10 times more expensive than V1.

Comment: I am using it to host my Function APP , not using it for anything else